# Not able to filter the list for listview.builder in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, filter, flutter-listview

I am trying to filter the JSON data while executing the below calling with `where`, but I am getting error

```
List filterproducts=[];
    filterproducts.addAll(widget.bomdatareceived[0]['bom_items'][0]['proc_code'].where((element) => element.contains(widget.processCode)).toList());
```

ERROR

```
    Class 'String' has no instance method 'where'.
Receiver: "61"
Tried calling: where(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic)
```

the `widget.proc_code` is `61` for example as from the below JSON data

JSON Data

```
"bom_items": [
               {
                     
                   "proc_code": "61",
                   "name": "SPINNING",
                   "bom_catalog_item": "327",
                  },
                  {
                     
                   "proc_code": "61",
                   "name": "SPINNING",
                   "bom_catalog_item": "390",
                   },
                   {
                     
                    "proc_code": "65",
                    "name": "DYING",
                    "bom_catalog_item": "1056",
                   }
                   ]
```

The above JSON data is on the list, I want to implement a filter kind of thing in this ListView.builder, to enlist only those elements which have same proc_code, I am not implementing any search bar kind of thing on the screen. I am receiving the value of proc_code from the previous screen and want to build the list which has the same proc_code.

Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
void main() {
final recievedItems =  { 
              "bom_items": [
               {
                     
                   "proc_code": "61",
                   "name": "SPINNING",
                   "bom_catalog_item": "327",
                  },
                  {
                     
                   "proc_code": "61",
                   "name": "SPINNING",
                   "bom_catalog_item": "390",
                   },
                   {
                     
                    "proc_code": "65",
                    "name": "DYING",
                    "bom_catalog_item": "1056",
                   }
                     ],
             };
  
  
  List filterproducts=[];
    filterproducts.addAll(recievedItems['bom_items'].where((element) => element.containsValue("61")).toList());
  print(filterproducts);  
}
```

This will return the items that contain `proc_code : 61`:

```
[{proc_code: 61, name: SPINNING, bom_catalog_item: 327}, {proc_code: 61, name: SPINNING, bom_catalog_item: 390}]
```

https://dartpad.dev/6e5efe3339d6ca62e2f42c557dfda012